# Set minimum width and height of a window to the minimum values from the embedded bound control at run time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientApp.Views.ModalWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" Height="332" Width="536" >

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=InlaidViewModel}" Margin="0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At run time, the `InlaidViewModel` binding on the `ContentControl` is set based on other values in the application.  How can I set the `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` on the `Window` to the same values on the embedded control when it's bound?  For example:

```
<Window x:Class="Roryap.BillCalendar.ClientApp.Views.ModalWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" Height="332" Width="536" 
        MinHeight="{Binding **what goes here**}" MinWidth="{Binding **what goes here**}">
```

I know I could add properties to the underlying view model for my `Window` to bind to for those values, but I'm not sure I want to do that, and this more of a curiosity.

The question is: if I don't want to have view model properties for `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` for my window, is there a way to inherit those values from an embedded control which is bound at run time?

Comment: The `UserControl` can traverse visual tree up until `Window`, that makes sense since embedded control define the size. Or you can simply use autosizable window (see [`SizeToContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx)), not really sure if it applies in your case.

Comment: If the embedded control is part of the same DOM and the same measure()/arrange() pass then you can just ref it's rendered size via like `MinHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=EmbeddedControlName}"` that is if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @ChrisW. -- I like where this is going.  I'm fairly inexperienced with XAML; can you elaborate on the control being part of the same DOM and measure/arrange pass?  When are those called?

Comment: @ChrisW. -- Sorry, rookie comment ^.  I'm reading up on it now.  This is a good post: http://csharpramblings.blogspot.com/2012/05/understanding-wpf-layout-system.html

Comment: Still, I'm not able to find information about how to arrange the layout of a container based on embedded controls that are the result of a runtime binding.

Comment: So the content template you're pushing into the embedded ContentControl has MinHeight/Width right? So when it renders in the ContentControl then it's size should be reflected in the size of the ContentControl. The measure/arrange pass does this work for you to determine the size needed for the contents as it draws the screen. You can bind to the rendered size of the ContentControl with ActualHeight/Width, except if you want to pass true values you'll have to bind them in the vm, butif you already have them hard set on the content of the control, why not just make them the same on the window.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly you should be able to bind to the MinHeight and MinWidth properties of the Content of the ControlControl like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientApp.Views.ModalWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="" Height="332" Width="536"
    MinHeight="{Binding Path=Content.MinHeight, ElementName=cc}"
    MinWidth="{Binding Path=Content.MinWidth, ElementName=cc}">

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
    <ContentControl x:Name="cc" Content="{Binding Path=InlaidViewModel}" Margin="0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

This assumes that whatever object the InlaidViewModel property returns has MinHeight and MinWidth properties of type System.Double:

```
public partial class ModalWindow : Window
{
    private readonly WindowViewModel _viewModel;
    public ModalWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new WindowViewModel();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
        Loaded += async (s, e) =>
        {
            _viewModel.InlaidViewModel = new InlaidViewModel();
            //wait 2 seconds before setting the MinHeight property
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            _viewModel.InlaidViewModel.MinHeight = 500;
        };
    }
}

public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private InlaidViewModel _inlaidViewModel;
    public InlaidViewModel InlaidViewModel
    {
        get { return  _inlaidViewModel; }
        set {  _inlaidViewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}

public class InlaidViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _minHeight;
    public double MinHeight
    {
        get { return _minHeight; }
        set { _minHeight = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can appreciate the approach since it's exactly what I show in comments, but what would the expected return of `Content.*` be? How would that be a valid property value to bind to where as ActualHeight/ActualWidth are the rendered sizes of the control and would provide a real value? I ask because I've never seen `Content.*` as an attached property of anything related an wouldn't mind learning something new if it exists?

Comment: As mentioned the expected return of Content would be an object that has a MinHeight and a MinWidth property, i.e. the "InlaidViewModel" object. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: @mm8 -- Thanks.  The idea is that I'd like to set the dimensions of the window and controls entirely in XAML without having to involve properties on the view.  I think Chris W.'s comment under my question is getting there, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you mean "involve properties of the view model"? If you want to bind the MinHeight property of the window to the ActualHeight property of the ContentControl itself you could just change the path of the bind to "ActualHeight": MinHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=cc}".